# Debian Server - Port 2015 ( cypress ) reported open by nmap

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, port

I'm running a headless Debian server as a media center with two services running: SSH and Jellyfin.

I decided to do an nmap scan this morning and it reported that port 2015 is open, which is apparently the service 'cypress'. I have no idea what this service is and have found virtually no information from search engines regarding it.

Is this something I should be concerned about? If I can't pinpoint exactly what this is I'll be wiping the server and doing a fresh install.

Thanks.

Nmap scan log:

```
root@debian:# nmap -sT -O -p 1-10000 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-04 04:07 AEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000077s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 9997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2015/tcp open  cypress
5000/tcp open  upnp
8096/tcp open  unknown
```

Comment: On my stock Debian 10 VM this port is not open. Try ss -punta on the your host to see who's listening to it.

Comment: Hi Peleion, the nmap scan was done locally on the Debian server.

Comment: Output from ss -punta: tcp LISTEN 0 128 127.0.0.1:2015 0.0.0.0:*

Comment: What's the process name listening to TCP 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service names are *meaningless;* the assignments exist to reduce collisions between services but they are not actually enforced in any way. Even legitimate services often don't bother to get their own port assignment and just pick whatever's handy – just look at how many miscellaneous things default to :1234 or :8000 or :9999 – and if you're worried that it might be an illegitimate service, it certainly won't care the slightest.

So in order to find out what service is listening on that port, you need to look at the *table of processes listening on ports* inside the server itself. On Linux the usual tools are *netstat* or *fuser* or *ss* – note that you **must run them with root privileges**:

```
sudo netstat -l -p -n -t | grep 2015

sudo fuser -v -n tcp 2015

sudo ss -l -p -n "sport = 2015"
```

From there you'll know the corresponding daemon's name and PID, and `/proc/<PID>/` is a good place to collect information about where the daemon's executable is, which cgroup (systemd service) it belongs to, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The netstat command was what I needed. The service on port 2015 ended up being my VPN listening on localhost. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/networking/index.html

Jellyfin admin networking setup doesn't mention port 2015 specifically but:

"Live TV devices will often use a random UDP port for HDHomeRun devices. The server will select an unused port on startup to connect to these tuner devices."

As in the comment,

```
# ss -punta
```

will list all the ports open on your server and what process is listening to them.